# how to get a function in Haskell to return more than one type using a data type?

Tags: haskell

So in my code I have the data type Token declared as:

```
data Token = Char | Int
deriving (Show,Eq,Ord)
```

and a function readIfNumber declared as

```
readIfNumber :: Char -> Token 
readIfNumber a 
    | isDigit a = Token (digitToInt a)
    | otherwise = Token a
```

but when I try to compile, the console returns an error of "expecting type Token, but got Char" or "expecting Token, but got Int" when an Int should be viewed as a Token, according to my declaration of Token. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: leftaroundabout's answer in all likelihood will solve your problem, but note that the code you posted doesn't actually match the error you describe. In future questions, please paste your code exactly as it is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In a variant type, you always need to be explicit about which of the options you take. I.e. you need to “label” the two branches unambiguously, with *constructors*. Like,

```
data Token = CharToken Char | IntToken Int
```

When actually building a token from either a char or int, you thereto wrap it in the suitable constructor:

```
readIfNumber a 
 | isDigit a = IntToken $ digitToInt a
 | otherwise = CharToken a
```

The reason this is required? Well, Haskell has full [type erasure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_erasure), i.e. types are completely traced, decided and optimised at compile time. At runtime, you wouldn't know whether the contained type was a char or int. Sometimes that's ok, namely when you have *polymorphic actions*. For example, `length` really doesn't care what the type of the *elements* contained in a list is, as it only deals with the *structure* of the list.

In this case however, somebody who receives a `Token` *will* need to know whether it's a char or int, to properly process it further. Hence the need to tag which type is contained.